# Frame-based and stream-based protocols

Tags: networking, websocket, protocols

I am reading [WebSocket specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.5), it's written:

> The WebSocket Protocol is designed on the principle that there should be minimal framing (the only framing that exists is to make the protocol frame-based instead of stream-based and to support a distinction between Unicode text and binary frames).

I don't understand what do `frame-based` and `stream-based` mean. Could you please provide examples of them with some basic explanation of the difference?

Comment: Frame-Based: If I told you that I'm sending you 8 bytes and I send you 6 bytes, you would wait for the next 2 bytes and than say "this is a message". Stream-Based: I send you 6 bytes. I send you 2 bytes. Is it one message? two messages? six messages? How do you know where one message starts and another begins?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A short overview:

**Frame-Based**: If I told you that I'm sending you 8 bytes and I send you 6 bytes, you would wait for the next 2 bytes and than say "this is a message".

**Stream-Based**: I send you 6 bytes. I send you 2 bytes. Is it one message? two messages? six messages? How do you know where one message starts and another begins?